# Mouse X , Y coordinates and duration at that coordinates

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am using the pyautogui to get the mouse X,Y coordinates as it moves along the screen . Is there some way I can get the duration of mouse hover at that coordinates like in milliseconds. I want to create a scatter plot of the mouse hover for instance I may be moving the mouse slowly over a particular section and fast over another. This way I can find which section has more focus.

Comment: Don’t you know when you polled each position (and hence the first and last of the same value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work really good as your scatterplot data

```
import pyautogui, time, sys ,random

while True:

    CurserPos = pyautogui.position()
    print(CurserPos, end='\r')
    pyautogui.move(random.randrange(0,100), random.randrange(0,100), 1, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)
    print(CurserPos, end='\r')
    pyautogui.move(random.randrange(0,100),random.randrange(0,100), 1, pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    print(CurserPos, end='\r')
    pyautogui.move(random.randrange(0,100),random.randrange(0,100), 1, pyautogui.easeInBounce)
    print(CurserPos, end='\r')
    pyautogui.move(random.randrange(0,100),random.randrange(0,100), 1, pyautogui.easeInQuad)
    print(CurserPos, end='\r')
    pyautogui.move(random.randrange(0,100),random.randrange(0,100), 1, pyautogui.easeInElastic)
```